# How do I edit web part text in the browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-parts

Just want to ask if anybody here knows how to edit a page online. I've been using Web Developer 2008. I've tried Web Parts tutorial of Asp.Net, and it only shows how to edit image, title of a tool like log in or calendar by using edit, design, catalog.

Is there a  way to edit a text in a certain page via online/browser view without going back to the webdev file to edit and update it? Because as I do the tutorial of web parts, it limits the editing and update portion to the image and other stuff, but not on the text part.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers (Chrome and IE in particular) have some built in developer tools that allow you to change the elements of a web page, among other things, including text. However, these changes *do not persist*. They are used for troubleshooting and/or manipulation of the elements to aid in design or tweaking the page (not just limited to that though).

If this is what you are trying to do, then you can open the developer tools in Chrome and in IE by clicking **F12** (windows).

Sounds like you are working with SharePoint webparts. [SharePoint Designer](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx) might be a tool worth looking at, depending on what you are doing.

**Edit:**

Another option is to develop a Custom Web Part Editor to achieve the functionality you are describing in your question. Here is a tutorial for [Creating a Custom Web Part Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx) that can get you started. Note: You will need VS2010 for this one.

Here is a comprehensive set of links from Scott Gu that can help you achieve this functionality for SharePoint 2007. [Writing Custom Web Parts for SharePoint 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/02/Writing-Custom-Web-Parts-for-SharePoint-2007.aspx).

Comment: no. what i mean is how to edit a real time/live site webpage?
that is restricted only to admin
I've tried using webparts in web developer, but it doesn't work good.

I've used Asp.Net VB Web Developer with SQL Server

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by `real time/live site webpage`. You can't edit a site you don't have access to. You should probably consult your system administrator.

Comment: I mean is, I am the admin and I want to edit my webpage on real time. how do I do that?

Comment: You can create a custom webpart that will allow you to make changes from the site. I'll update my answer with a link to a tutorial that can show you how.

Comment: hello rich, can I have your update for the link to a tutorial that you will show to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Jelliphy**. Jelliphy is a tool that allows any users to edit any text of a web page, and also to move and resize elements in the page, to draw on the page, to edit the images and much more.

[Jelliphy Lite](http://www.dispage.com/?show_bookmarklet) and [Jelliphy Extended](http://www.dispage.com/?show_bookmarklet=ext) are bookmarklets that you can use with any browser for free: just go to the page to change and click the Jelliphy link from your favorites.

There are several ways to edit text with Jelliphy: for example you can switch to the "Handle Mode" (the second button in the Main Panel), then double-click the text to change and edit it.